# Alias in .bashrc doesn't seem to accept an argument

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

I'm trying to setup an alias in my .bashrc file, but it's not working as expected.

I have this alias which works:

```
alias lolcat='python /home/martyn/Dropbox/Applications/Scripts/logcat-viewer/unixcoloredlogcat.py'
```

and I normally use this command as such:

```
adb logcat SomeValue:* *:e | lolcat
```

But I want to put that in to an alias so that I can write:

```
logcat SomeValue
```

but my alias below isn't working - it seems that the $1 isn't coming through - can anyone help me fix this?

```
alias logcat="adb lolcat $1:* *:E | lolcat"
```

** FIX **

```
alias lolcat='python /home/martyn/Dropbox/Applications/Scripts/logcat-viewer/unixcoloredlogcat.py'

function logcat(){ 
    adb lolcat $1:* *:E | lolcat 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used. See [Bash Reference Manual::6.6 Aliases](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases)

Comment: Ah - thank you.  have added fix to comment