# A short way to call my bash script instead of use Source command

Tags: bash, shell-script

My script use and modifies a shell variable. I need to always use:

```
source myscript
```

Is there a shorter way to call this script and have it modify the current shell's environment?

It can be elegantly done by using functions use as described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47751/20029), but I need a faster way.

Comment: Do you mean faster as in - faster execution (performance), or faster setup (not having to modify `.bashrc`)? I ask because it never occurred to me wrapping it in a function would imply a performance deficit (if this is indeed the case). I suppose I could test this with `time`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.` as a shorthand for `source`. From the `bash(1)` man page:

```
.  filename [arguments]
source filename [arguments]

Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell environment and return
the exit status of the last command executed from filename.
```

Comment: Note that `.` is the POSIX standard name for this command (`source` is a bash-specific synonym).