# Executing user defined function in a find -exec call

Tags: shell-script, find, solaris, ksh, function

I'm on Solaris 10 and I have tested the following with ksh (88), bash (3.00) and zsh (4.2.1).

The following code doesn't yield any result:

```
function foo {
    echo "Hello World"
}

find somedir -exec foo \;
```

The find does match several files (as shown by replacing `-exec ...` with `-print`), and the function works perfectly when called outside from the `find` call.

Here's what the `man find` page say about `-exec`:

```
 -exec command       True if the executed command  returns  a
                     zero  value  as  exit status. The end of
                     command must be punctuated by an escaped
                     semicolon (;).  A command argument {} is
                     replaced by the current pathname. If the
                     last  argument  to  -exec  is {} and you
                     specify + rather than the semicolon (;),
                     the command is invoked fewer times, with
                     {} replaced by groups of  pathnames.  If
                     any  invocation of the command returns a
                     non-zero  value  as  exit  status,  find
                     returns a non-zero exit status.
```

I could probably get away doing something like this:

```
for f in $(find somedir); do
    foo
done
```

But I'm afraid of dealing with field separator issues.

Is it possible to call a shell function (defined in the same script, let's not bother with scoping issues) from a `find ... -exec ...` call?

I tried it with both `/usr/bin/find` and `/bin/find` and got the same result.

Comment: did you try exporting the function after you declare it? `export -f foo`

Comment: You will need to make the function an external script and put it in `PATH`.  Alternatively, use `sh -c '...'` and both define AND run the function in the `...` bit.  It may help to understand the [differences between functions and scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30964/9537).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A `function` is local to a shell, so you'd need `find -exec` to spawn a shell and have that function defined in that shell before being able to use it. Something like:

```
find ... -exec ksh -c '
  function foo {
    echo blan: "$@"
  }
  foo "$@"' ksh {} +
```

`bash` allows one to export functions via the environment with `export -f`, so you can do (in bash):

```
foo() { ...; }
export -f foo
find ... -exec bash -c 'foo "$@"' bash {} +
```

`ksh88` has `typeset -fx` to export function (not via the environment), but that can only be used by she-bang less scripts executed by `ksh`, so not with `ksh -c`.

Another option is to do:

```
find ... -exec ksh -c "
  $(typeset -f foo)"'
  foo "$@"' ksh {} +
```

That is, use `typeset -f` to dump the definition of the `foo` function inside the inline script. Note that if `foo` uses other functions, you'll also need to dump them as well.

Or instead of passing the function definition on the command line (which would be visible in the output of `ps -f` for instance), you can pass it via an environment variable:

```
FUNCDEFS=$(typeset -f foo) find ... -exec ksh -c '
  eval "$FUNCDEFS" &&
    unset -v FUNCDEFS &&
    foo "$@"' ksh {} +
```

(the `unset -v FUNCDEFS` to avoid polluting the environment of commands started by that `foo` function if any).

Comment: Can you explain why there are two occurrences of `ksh` or `bash` in the `-exec` command? I understand the first, but not the second occurrence.

Comment: @danielkullmann In `bash -c 'some-code' a b c`, `$0` is `a`, `$1` is `b`..., so if you want `$@` to be `a, b, c` you need to insert something before. Because `$0` is also used when displaying error messages, it's a good idea to use the name of the shell, or something that makes sense in that context.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you for such nice answer.

Comment: Remember to `export -f some_function` as well as `export some_var`.

Answer (score 11):

Use \0 as a delimiter and read the filenames into the current process from a spawned command, like so:

```
foo() {
  printf "Hello {%s}\n" "$1"
}

while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do
  foo "${filename}" </dev/null
done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -print0)
```

What's going on here:

- `read -d ''` reads until the next \0 byte, so you don't have to worry about strange characters in filenames.
- similarly, `-print0` uses \0 to terminate each generated filename instead of \n.
- the `-r` option (raw) prevents backslash escaping in the filename
- `cmd2 < <(cmd1)` is the same as `cmd1 | cmd2` except that cmd2 is run in the main shell and not a subshell.
- the call to foo is redirected from `/dev/null` to ensure it doesn't accidentally read from the pipe.
- `$filename` is quoted so the shell doesn't try to split a filename that contains whitespace.
- `IFS=` prevents Bash from stripping trailing whitespace from the filenames (thanks [DanielSmedegaardBuus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30193/danielsmedegaardbuus) for this correction)

Now, `read -d` and `<(...)` are in zsh, bash and ksh 93u, but I'm not sure about earlier ksh versions.

Comment: much faster than standard answer but slightly less than using a for loop: `time find . -type d -exec bash -c 'dosomething "$0"' {} \;
real    0m16.102s `  `time while read -d '' filename; do   dosomething "${filename}" </dev/null; done < <(find . -type d -print0)
real    0m0.355s`  `time for dir in $(find . -type d); do dosomething $dir; done
real    0m0.339s`   (1465 dirs, on standard hard drive armv7l GNU/Linux synology_armada38x_ds218j)

Comment: readable benchmark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67780632/1767316)

Comment: @user1767316 The problem with a for loop is that it requires generating a complete list of files and then iterating over that list, potentially exhausting shell size limits. Reading from a piped input requires no caching, and won't test any limits. It will work regardless of the amount of filenames being discovered by the `find` command.

Comment: Actually, there's one thing missing here, because even with `-print0` and `-d ''`, you'd think that funky file names such as those with leading or trailing whitespace would be good, but no. Bash will trim that whitespace off. To prevent this from happening, you can do `while IFS= read -d '' filename; do`. What a crazy mistress the shell is. OMG.

Answer (score 10):

if you want a child process, spawned from your script, to use a pre-defined shell function you need to export it with `export -f <function>`

NOTE: `export -f` is bash specific

since only a *shell* can run *shell* functions:

```
find / -exec /bin/bash -c 'function "$1"' bash {} \;
```

EDIT: essentially your script should resemble this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function foo() { do something; }
export -f foo
find somedir -exec /bin/bash -c 'foo "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: `export -f` is a syntax error in `ksh`, and prints the function definition to the screen in `zsh`. In all of `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash`, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: `find / -exec /bin/bash -c 'function' \;`

Comment: Now it works, but only with `bash`. Thank you!

Comment: Never embed `{}` in the shell code! That means the file name is interpreted as shell code so is very dangerous

Answer (score 7):

This is not always applicable, but when it is, it's a simple solution. Set the `globstar` option (`set -o globstar` in ksh93, `shopt -s globstar` in bash ≥4; it's on by default in zsh). Then use `**/` to match the current directory and its subdirectories recursively.

For example, instead of `find . -name '*.txt' -exec somecommand {} \;`, you can run

```
for x in **/*.txt; do somecommand "$x"; done
```

Instead of `find . -type d -exec somecommand {} \;`, you can run

```
for d in **/*/; do somecommand "$d"; done
```

Instead of `find . -newer somefile -exec somecommand {} \;`, you can run

```
for x in **/*; do
  [[ $x -nt somefile ]] || continue
  somecommand "$x"
done
```

When `**/` doesn't work for you (because your shell doesn't have it, or because you need a `find` option that doesn't have a shell analogue), [define the function in the `find -exec` argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50695).

Comment: I cannot seem to find a `globstar` option on the version of ksh (`ksh88`) I'm using.

Comment: @rahmu Indeed, it's new in ksh93. Doesn't Solaris 10 have a ksh93 somewhere?

Comment: According to [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/OTNGarage/entry/new_shell_in_oracle_solaris) ksh93 has been introduced in Solaris 11 to replace both the Bourne Shell and ksh88...

Comment: @rahmu. Solaris has had ksh93 for a while as `dtksh` (ksh93 with some X11 extensions), but an old version and possibly part of an optional package where CDE is optional.

Comment: It should be noted that recursive globbing differs from `find` in that it excludes dotfiles and doesn't descend into dotdirs and that it sorts the file list (both of which can be addresses in zsh through globbing qualifiers). Also with `**/*` as opposed to `./**/*`, filenames may start with `-`.