# Find functions, commands, and builtins

Tags: bash, shell, find, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Executing user defined function in a find -exec call](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50692/executing-user-defined-function-in-a-find-exec-call)

Suppose I have the following bash code:

```
!#/bin/bash
function  print_echo (){
    echo "This is print_echo Function" $1;
}
find ./ -iname "*" -exec print_echo {} \;
```

For each `-exec` command i get the following error:

```
find: `print_echo': No such file or directory
```

NOTE: Before it , i tested it for a critical program , and solved my program with another algorithm but it's a question: *Why find command doesn't accept built-in bash command and function name as argument of `-exec`?*

Comment: A side point - `find` with no args has the same behavior as `find ./ -iname "*"`. Current directory and "match everything" is implied.

Comment: @jordanm, `find` without file arguments is not standard/portable, but it's true that the `-iname "*"` is superfluous. Another side point: use the Bourne function syntax (`f() { ...; }`) or the ksh syntax (`function f { ...; }`), not that bastard one (`function f() { ...; }`) which is only recognised by accident by `bash` (because it ignores `function`) and is the syntax of no shell.

Comment: Of course -exec has problem with any bash built-in command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` does not accept your function as a command because its `-exec` predicate literally calls C library `exec` function to start the program. Your function is available only to the bash interpreter itself. Even if you define your function inside your `.bashrc` file it will be 'visible' only to the `bash`.

So, if you really need two execute with find's `-exec` some custom sequence of commands  put it into a separate script file or use other workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why `find` does not like function. The work around is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
function  print_echo (){
    echo "This is print_echo Function" $1;
}

for f in $(find . -iname "*")
do
    print_echo $f
done
```

#### Update

The above script does not work with files that have embedded spaces. The following update does:

```
#!/bin/bash
function  print_echo (){
    echo "This is print_echo Function" $1;
}

find . -iname "*.sh" | \
while read f
do
    print_echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thank you Hai, But my question is conceptually ,,,,, not coding....

Comment: I understand, but I cannot answer that. I'm in the same boat.

Comment: May be developer of find can answer us.... by the way , your solution is very good solution. thank you.

Comment: This will break on any file containing a space.

Comment: change the field separator to new line (`IFS=$'\n'`) should make the `for` loop work if file name contains white spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can launch a bash interpreter in the `-exec` argument of find. This is not efficient if your function only accepts a single filename at a time, as it will have to redeclare the function each time. You can design it so that it accepts a list of files and use the `+` terminator to find so that the shell is only spanwed once. Here is an example.

```
find -exec bash -c '
    print_echo() { 
        printf "This is print_echo Function: %s\n" "$@" 
    }
    print_echo "$@"
    ' find-bash {} +
```

At this point, there is not reason to declare the function. Just execute what the function would have done inside of the `bash -c`.