# Blank lines when executing "grep | xargs" in a "find -exec"

Tags: shell, grep, find, xargs

I'm trying to list all directories of a web server that are blocked by Apache via a `.htaccess` (containing `deny from all`).
I've managed to get the list of blocking `.htaccess` but when I try to extract the directory path using `dirname` I have some errors:

1. List of `.htaccess` files:

   ```
   find . -type f -name ".htaccess"
   ./.htaccess
   ./config/.htaccess
   ./files/.htaccess
   ./plugins/webservices/.htaccess
   ./plugins/webservices/scripts/.htaccess
   ./install/mysql/.htaccess
   ./scripts/.htaccess
   ./locales/.htaccess
   ```
2. List of blocking `.htaccess` files:

   ```
   find . -type f -name ".htaccess" -exec sh -c "grep -Eli '^deny from all$' '{}'" \;
   ./config/.htaccess
   ./files/.htaccess
   ./plugins/webservices/scripts/.htaccess
   ./install/mysql/.htaccess
   ./scripts/.htaccess
   ./locales/.htaccess
   ```
3. Error come the errors. Same list as in 2. but using `xargs` and `dirname` to get the containing directory:

   ```
   find . -type f -name ".htaccess" -exec sh -c "grep -Eli '^deny from all$' '{}' | xargs dirname" \;
   dirname: missing operand
   Try dirname --help' for more information
   ./config
   ./files
   dirname: missing operand
   Try dirname --help' for more information
   ./plugins/webservices/scripts
   ./install/mysql
   ./scripts
   ./locales
   ```
4. Debug attempt of list 3: we can see 2 blank lines where the 2 errors were:

   ```
   find . -type f -name ".htaccess" -exec sh -c "grep -Eli '^deny from all$' '{}' | xargs echo" \;

   ./config/.htaccess
   ./files/.htaccess

   ./plugins/webservices/scripts/.htaccess
   ./install/mysql/.htaccess
   ./scripts/.htaccess
   ./locales/.htaccess
   ```

Theses 2 blank lines obviously matches the 2 `.htaccess` files that were ignore because they don't contains `deny from all`. I don't understand why I get these in lists 3. and 4. but not in 2.

Comment: By the way, putting the `{}` within the shell command is a major security risk.  If you ever need that effect (which you don't here, anyway), use [this pattern](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50695/135943) instead.  (Set the found filename as a shell positional parameter and refer to it as such.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because when the grep doesn't match, you're not passing anything to xargs.

For example:

1. `find` gets `./.htaccess` and calls your `-exec`.
2. The `grep` doesn't match anything in the file, so it outputs nothing
3. `xargs` launches `dirname` without any arguments, and so `dirname` thinks it was just misused and displays its help message.

The proper way to do this:

```
find . -type f -name .htaccess -exec grep -iq '^deny from all$' {} \; -printf '%h\n'
```

Comment: Thanks: works just fine and is simpler. I now do get why the blank lines: is there a way to skip/ignore them prior to calling `xargs` (not all cases can be resolved only via `find` :p)?

Comment: @CDuv `--no-run-if-empty`. However find is much safer. It will handle things that the grep/pipe method can't, such as filenames with newlines in them.

Answer (score 0):

You've got this error:

> `dirname: missing operand.`
>   `Try dirname --help' for more information`

because `dirname` has missing operand (nothing was passed as an argument). This happened, because `grep` returned empty results.

If you're using GNU `xargs`, you can use `-r` (`--no-run-if-empty`) to not run the command, when input is empty (does not contain any nonblanks).

To make it work with BSD `xargs`, you probably need to rewrite you command to check whether the input is empty and run the command accordingly. Or just ignore the error by suppressing stderr, for example:

> `find . ... -exec sh -c "grep ... | xargs dirname 2> /dev/null || true" ';'`

Or you can use while loop, so you can avoid parsing empty files or having problems with spaces in filenames, e.g.

```
find . -type f -name ".htaccess" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do

    grep -Eli '^deny from all$' "$file" | while IFS= read -r -d '' deny_file; do
      dirname "$deny_file"
    done

done
```