# how to execute a shell built-in if find found certain files

Tags: shell, find

In general, if we want to execute a command if `find` identifies files corresponding to certain specs, we can use `-exec`. But in my case I want to exit the shell/script if `find` found a match and `-exec` can't do that. [Apparently `find`'s `-exec` [cannot call bash functions either](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50692/executing-user-defined-function-in-a-find-exec-call).)

For instance in a script to remove a tree if and only if it contains only empty directories, I'd like to first check for presence of any non-directory and abort with an error message at the first such unexpected entry.

So far whenever I need to do something like this, I put the output to a variable (possibly using `-quit` with `find`) and testing for it being empty or not.

So my script looks like:

```
#! /bin/sh
INTRUDER="$(find "$@" ! -type d -print -quit)"
if [ -n "$INTRUDER" ] ; then
    echo "Found non-dir $INTRUDER; leaving the arguments untouched"
    exit 1
fi
rm -R "$@"
```

Is there a different/better approach than this? By "better" I mean, smaller to code, more portable (if there is any portability issue with the above), etc. By "different" I mean by avoiding the extra variable and testing for its length.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop the find command after first match?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your attention. I (already noted that I) know about `-quit`. But it merely stops searching after first match. I am asking for a workaround to not being able to `-exec` a shell built-in (for this particular example to exit the shell, not exit the `find`). So this is not a dup. Please remove that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
find "$@" ! -type d -exec kill -9 $$ \; -quit && rm -R "$@"
```

- If `find` exits normally (nothing is found) `rm -R "$@"` will be executed.
- If `find` finds something the current shell/script is killed (`$$` stores the pid). The `rm`-part will never be executed in this case.

Comment: Hi -- that's a neat trick! I'll wait and see if there's another answer though.

Comment: ... and it's limited to stopping the current script and doesn't allow to output an exit status, does it?

Comment: If the rm part is executed the command returns the exit status of `rm` (0, 1 or 2). If it's killed the return value `$?` (of the script) is 137 (see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) 137 means 128+9 that the script is killed by signal #9 (`SIGKILL`).

Comment: @jamadagni You can trap the signal if you want to change the exit status.

Comment: @chaos: I'm sure a killed app will have an exit status. I meant about controlling the exit status like Gilles said. @Gilles: Thanks. Using `trap "exit 1" SIGKILL` does fine.