# Transforming a list of files separated by new lines into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, filenames

**Goal:** I'm trying to find all instances of `*.clj` or `*.cljs` files recursively within a directory, store them in a string variable (separated by new lines) and then transform them.

So if the following `clj(s)` files are found within my directory `dir1`:

```
/dir1/dir2/hello1.clj
/dir1/dir2/hello2.clj
/dir1/dir2/hello3.cljs
/dir1/dir2/hello4.clj
/dir1/dir2/hello5.cljs
```

And my transformation is, let's say, merely to return the basename of each of these strings:

```
/dir1/dir2/hello1.clj -> hello1.clj
/dir1/dir2/hello2.clj -> hello2.clj
/dir1/dir2/hello3.clj -> hello3.clj
/dir1/dir2/hello4.clj -> hello4.clj
/dir1/dir2/hello5.clj -> hello5.clj
```

Then how can I write a function `f` such that

```
$ VAR=$(f dir1)
```

satisfies

```
$ echo "$VAR"
  hello1.clj
  hello2.clj
  hello3.clj
  hello4.clj
  hello5.clj
```

?

**Attempt:**

I know that I can generate the `.clj` and `.cljs` files of a directory via

```
FOUND_FILES=$(find "dir1" -type f -regex ".*\.\(clj\|cljs\)")
```

and that I can use the `basename` command to get the basename of a file. How to do the rest?

Comment: You can safely assume that there no files with whitespace characters (especially spaces) in their names?

Comment: @phk: Yes, we can assume that.

Comment: [See here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50692) how to run `find` and `-exec` a function...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [globs](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) and [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). You don't need to use `find` if you have a version of bash that has `globstar` to enable `**` syntax (bash4+).

```
# Enable `**`, and expand globs to 0 elements if unmatched
shopt -s globstar nullglob
# Put all files matching *.clj or *.cljs into ${files[@]} recursively
files=(dir1/**/*.clj{,s})
# Print all files delimited by newlines, with all leading directories stripped
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]##*/}"
```

To apply some arbitrary transformation, replace the last line with:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    some-arbitrary-transformation <<< "$file"
done
```

Comment: In my actual use case, I'm not trying to get a file's basename, but rather have my own transformation `t` in mind. How could I apply `t` to each line of `files` as you've got it here?

Comment: @George See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
var="$(echo **/*.clj **/*.cljs | xargs -n1 basename)"
echo "$var"
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't work if `basename` is a custom function defined above. How can it made to work for custom functions defined within the same shell script?

Comment: Add full path to basename, e.g. /usr/bin/basename

Comment: That assumes that the custom function is contained within a separate shell script. Is there a way to do use a custom function defined within the same shell script (i.e. `custom_function` is defined a few lines above)?

Comment: or use GNU find: `var=$(find "dir1" -type f -regex ".*\.\(clj\|cljs\)$" -printf "%f\n")`

Comment: This breaks on whitespace due to failure to use a delimiter that's not permitted in POSIX filenames.