# Running a Bash function for each file found with the find command

Tags: bash, find

I currently have this command, which successfully prints each file name on its own line:

```
find . -exec echo {} \;
```

I'm trying to split the logic so that the `find` command executes a function. Based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50692/executing-user-defined-function-in-a-find-exec-call) I've tried this:

```
my_function() {
    echo $1
}
export -f my_function
find . -exec bash -c 'my_function "$@"' bash {} +
```

Then I get this output:

```
.
```

I also tried replacing `$@` with `$*` but this causes `$1` to be every single file without line breaks. I would like to run logic that checks each file, so I would like `$1` to just be one file at a time. I tried splitting the output with spaces via `for file in $1` but this doesn't work for files that have spaces in the file name. How do I run a Bash function for every file found by the `find` command?

EDIT: Here's the whole script I am using. It seems to work fine.

```
# Ensures that non-csproj text files are formatted with LF line endings.
format() {
    for pathname do
        if [[ $pathname == *"git"* ]]; then
            continue
        elif [[ $pathname == *"csproj"* ]]; then
            continue
        fi
        dos2unix $pathname
    done
}
export -f format
find . -exec bash -c 'format "$@"' bash {} \;
```

Comment: Change  `$1`  to `"$1"` aka Quote your variable.

Comment: What are you expecting that test against `*git*` to do? Do you intend to test against the filename, or, like you're currently doing, the whole pathname?

Comment: I want the script to ignore the `.git` folder. It doesn't need to be perfect, but if you have a better way I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run `dos2unix --newline` on every regular file in and below the current directory, avoiding any file whose name contains the string `git`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*git*' -exec dos2unix --newline {} +
```

That is, find all regular files whose names do not match the pattern `*git*`, and run `dos2unix --newline` on all of these in as large batches as possible at once.  Change `! -name '*git*'` to `! -path '*git*'` to avoid any file whose pathname contains the string `git` (e.g. files in `.git` directories).

To explicitly avoid any `.git` directories, but to include anything else that may have `git` in its name:

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -type f -exec dos2unix --newline {} +
```

This stops `find` form even entering any directory called `.git` by using `-prune` to delete such paths from the search tree.

---

Answer before edit to the question:

Your function prints out its first argument only.  The dot is the top-level search path that you use with `find`.  It gets passed as you don't do any particular filtering of the directory entries (as with, for example, `-type f` for regular files only, or `-name`, or any other type of `find` test).

If you want your function to print each of its arguments, use either

```bash
my_function() {
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
```

which lets `printf` print each of the arguments with a newline in-between, or

```bash
my_function() {
    for pathname do
        printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
    done
}
```

which loops over the arguments and calls `printf` once for each.

This would be expected to work correctly if you called the function like

```
my_function "$@"
```

from within your in-line `bash -c` script.  The `"$@"` expands to all the arguments given to the script, individually quoted.

Another way would be to move the looping into the `bash -c` script:

```
for pathname do
    my_function "$pathname"
done
```

and then have

```bash
my_function () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1"
}
```

This would be explicitly doing what you say you'd want to do, i.e. call the function once for each pathname.

The `find` command would then look either like

```bash
find . -exec bash -c 'for pathname do my_function "$pathname"; done' bash {} +
```

or, arguably a bit more readable,

```bash
find . -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        my_function "$pathname"
    done' bash {} +
```

This would, incidentally, be the same as

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

for pathname in ./**/*; do
    my_function "$pathname"
done
```

except that `.` would not be processed.  Using this, you would not have to export your `my_function` function.

With the loop inside the function (as in the first two pieces of code in this answer), this would be shortened to

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

my_function ./**/*
```

Comment: One word about why you pass `bash` before `{}` would **_really_** be useful. It took me a while to understand it.

Comment: @Enlico It's a string that is put into `$0` and should be the name of the shell (it will be used in error messages). Without that string, the first found file would be passed to the `bash -c` script in `$0`, which means it would not be part of the loop.