# Executing user defined function in a find -exec call AND choosing version of that function based on arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find, function

This was my starting point: shell script - [Executing user defined function in a find -exec call - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50692/executing-user-defined-function-in-a-find-exec-call)

But I need to choose between 2 different versions of the function, based on an argument passed to the containing script. I have a working version, but it has a lot of duplicate code. I'm trying to implement it better, but I can't quite figure out how to do that in this context.

Here's the core code:

```
cmd_force() {
  git fetch; 
  git reset --hard HEAD; 
  git merge '@{u}:HEAD';
  newpkg=$(makepkg --packagelist);
  makepkg -Ccr; 
  repoctl add -m $newpkg;
}

cmd_nice() {
  git pull;
  newpkg=$(makepkg --packagelist);
  makepkg -Ccr; 
  repoctl add -m $newpkg;
}

if [[ $force == "y" ]] ; then
  export -f cmd_force
  find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name PKGBUILD -execdir bash -c 'cmd_force' bash {} \;
else
  echo "Call this with the -f option in case of: error: Your local changes to ... files would be overwritten by merge"
  export -f cmd_nice
  find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name PKGBUILD -execdir bash -c 'cmd_nice' bash {} \;
fi
```

I don't think I should have to have two independent functions. There are only a few lines that differ. The actual functions have a lot more code, but it is completely duplicated between them.

I did not include my code for parsing the argument because I'm learning about [getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29754866) and haven't finished that part yet.

Comment: Why not also `export force` and move the `if [[ $force == "y" ]]` into the function?

Comment: @meuh I like that idea. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export `force` too and move the `if [[ $force == "y" ]]` into the function:

```bsh
cmd() {
  if [[ $force == "y" ]] ; then
    git fetch; 
    git reset --hard HEAD; 
    git merge '@{u}:HEAD';
  else
    git pull;
  fi
  newpkg=$(makepkg --packagelist);
  makepkg -Ccr; 
  repoctl add -m $newpkg;
}

export -f cmd
export force
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name PKGBUILD -execdir bash -c 'cmd' bash {} \;
```

Comment: Exported bash functions are a securty risk, unless this is limited to the scope of a script.

Comment: @schily - what is the best solution in this case?

Comment: Not using this feature in other cases.

Comment: @schily - it was nice of you to point out the potential security risk, but you have given so little info that it is of no help to me. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function name as an argument:

```
if [[ $force == "y" ]] ; then
  USE=cmd_force
else
  echo "Call this with the -f option in case of: error: Your local changes to ... files would be overwritten by merge"
  USE=cmd_nice
fi

export -f $USE
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name PKGBUILD -execdir bash -c $USE' {}' \;
```