# Shellscript which copies all files automatically per ftp

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ftp

today I wrote a script which should copy all files per ftp to my destination server.

Script is executed inside zsh-shell, so I guess I should use "sh script.sh" to execute it correctly?

Also I pasted my script to https://www.shellcheck.net/, which says its fine, but inside my zsh-shell I get following errors:

`upload_file: command not found`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FTP_SERVER=ftp.ip
FTP_USER=ftp.user
FTP_PASS=ftp.passwd

FTP_DESTINATION_DIR="/destination_directory"

LOCAL_SOURCE_DIR="/home/$USER/pictures/local_pictures"

function upload_file {
  local file=$1
  echo "Hochladen von Datei $file"
  ftp -inv "$FTP_SERVER" << EOF
user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS
binary
cd $FTP_DESTINATION_DIR
put $file
quit
EOF
}

find "$LOCAL_SOURCE_DIR" \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \) -exec bash -c 'upload_file "$0"' {} \;
```

I am not very used to this kind of scripting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the function you declare is not visible to the second `bash` instance you run from `find ... -exec`. https://shellcheck.net/ probably just sees a single-quoted literal string, and does not look inside it for problems.

Using `sh` to run a Bash script could also be a problem. Your script doesn't use any Bash features other than the nonstandard `function` declaration, but there is really no reason to prefer that over the standard POSIX function declaration syntax. (If `sh` is a symlink to Bash on your system, it probably works even though many Bash-only features will be turned off when it is invoked as `sh`. But you shoud still understand the difference, and use `bash` to run Bash scripts.)

Anyway, the preferred mechanism is to `chmod +x` the script, and then simply run it by specifying its path (or just its name, if the directory it's in is on your `PATH`). This allows the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to select the correct interpreter. (It's simply ignored as a comment if you explicitly run the script with `sh` or `bash`, or even something completely wrong like `python` or `csh`).

With these details fixed, your script would look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

FTP_SERVER=ftp.ip
FTP_USER=ftp.user
FTP_PASS=ftp.passwd

FTP_DESTINATION_DIR="/destination_directory"

LOCAL_SOURCE_DIR="/home/$USER/pictures/local_pictures"

upload_file () {
  local file=$1
  echo "Hochladen von Datei $file"
  ftp -inv "$FTP_SERVER" <<EOF
user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS
binary
cd $FTP_DESTINATION_DIR
put $file
quit
EOF
}

export -f upload_file

find "$LOCAL_SOURCE_DIR" \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \) -exec bash -c 'upload_file "$0"' {} \;
```

A better fix still would be to allow `upload_file` to accept multiple file names, and only create one FTP session.

```
:
upload_file () {
  ( printf '%s\n' \
      "user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS" \
      "binary" \
      "cd $FTP_DESTINATION_DIR"
    local file
    for file; do
        # print diagnostics to stderr
        echo "Hochladen von Datei $file" >&2
        echo "put $file"
    done
    echo "quit" ) |
  ftp -inv "$FTP_SERVER"
}

export -f upload_file

find "$LOCAL_SOURCE_DIR" \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \) \
    -exec bash -c 'upload_file "$@"' _ {} +
```

Tangentially, probably don't use an `.sh` extension on your shell scripts, especially if they are not actually `sh` scripts. There is no strong convention around this, but `ls` doesn't have an extension, either; why should it?

Comment: I guess the round parentheses in the body of the updated function could be replaced with curlies to avoid spawning a subshell, but I'm not in a place where I can test that. You'll need a newline or a semicolon before the closing curly then.

Comment: unfortunately I can not establish connection to ftp host :/

If i connect manually with ftp server_ip and insert my username and passwd it works, but I need to do it in one action :/

Loop is correct and find all occurences, in my case all pictures, but establishing a connection to ftp always fails..

Comment: The stock `ftp` client may not be properly scriptable. Sometimes you can work around this with a strategically placed `sleep` or etc but ultimately in this scenario the robust solution is to use a client with scripting support (it's been a while, but I recall using `lftp` and `ncftp` back in the day) or move to a scripting language like Python, whose standard `ftplib` module should be straightforward to figure out.

Comment: alright, python is always an acceptable solution for me!
thanks for this advices! :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `upload_file` is a function that is available only in your script but not exported to the `bash` environment called by `find`.

To fix this, you can [export the function](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch29_13.htm) using this:

```bash
typeset -fx upload_file
```

Put that before you call the `find` command, and it should work as intended.

---

Edit: tripleee pointed out in the comments that **`export -f`** could also be used. Which is arguably much more readable.

Comment: jup, I just used triplee suggestions, thanks anyways kind stranger!

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you are not declaring function properly. Assuming from the output, and behavior you are missing parentheses `function upload_file {...` should be `function upload_file (){...` (after you edited the question that is not a problem anymore I assume).
In bash you should export the function so it is visible when you execute `bash -c` in `find` step:

```
export -f upload_file
find "$LOCAL_SOURCE_DIR"...
```

As you can see in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50695/409225).

Comment: @Zaidhaan Hussain has has already answered...