# find (fd) execute with custom function and multiple parameters

Tags: bash, find, fd

I'm quite new to bash scripting so excuse the rough script.  I'm writing a simple script that goes through all directories that has a `.git` directory in them, and checks if the worktree is clean or dirty.  It works, **but** I want to have 3 parameters:

- rootDir: top level directory to search for .git directories.
- status: `clean|dirty|all` which will filter the output based on the status of the direcotries
- separator: Allows passing null which would do a `\0` separator so that I can pass this output to `xargs` and further run commands while supporting paths with spaces.

The problem I'm facing is with passing parameters from the `fd` `exec` to my `isRepoDirty` function.  The `$cleanOrDirty` parameter somehow makes it in, but the `$separator` parameter doesn't work.  My single quote, double quote knowledge is a bit shaky here...  If I have my params inside the single quotes, they never get expanded.

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
# DOES NOT WORK IN ZSH!
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50692/executing-user-defined-function-in-a-find-exec-call

rootDir=$1
cleanOrDirty=$2
separator=$3

# echo "Root: $rootDir"
# echo "Clean or Dirty: $cleanOrDirty"
# echo "Separator: $separator"

function isRepoDirty() {
    if [[ $(git --git-dir "$1" --work-tree "$1/.." status --porcelain | wc -l) > 0 ]]; then
        status="dirty"
    else
        status="clean"
    fi

    # echo "Repo: $1, Status: $status"
    if [[ $2 == $status || $2 == "all" ]]; then
        # echo "Separator: $3"
        if [[ $3 == "null" ]]; then
            printf "%b" "$1/..\0"
        else
            echo "$1/.."
        fi
    fi
}
export -f isRepoDirty

fd --no-ignore --hidden -t d "\.git$" $rootDir -x /bin/bash -c 'isRepoDirty "{}" '$cleanOrDirty $separator
```

If my approach to this is totally off, please do tell me as I'm quit keen to learn and do what's considered best practise.  Heh my passing of args is a bit rudimentary.  I haven't found a simple way to easily handle `-p` and `--parameter-name` style arguments easily in bash.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by adding a `bash` argument, like so:

```
bash -c 'command "$@"' bash arg1 arg2
```

as Stéphane Chazelas noted, the first argument is treated as `$0` to the called command, so this will make debugging easier than `_`, which is what I originally had.

In your case, I think the answer would look like so:

```
fd --no-ignore --hidden -t d '\.git$' "$rootDir" -x /bin/bash -c 'isRepoDirty "$1" "$2" "$3"' bash {} "$cleanOrDirty" "$separator"
```

Note that it assumes that `$rootDir` doesn't start with `-` and that none of `$cleanOrDirty` and `$separator` is `;` or contains `{}`, `{/}`, `{//}`, `{.}`, `{/.}`.

To avoid those, you could use the `--` option delimiter, meaning moving `-x` before the pattern, and pass the contents of those extra variables via the environment rather than arguments:

```
(
  export cleanOrDirty separator
  exec fd --no-ignore --hidden -t d -x /bin/bash -c '
    isRepoDirty "$1" "$cleanOrDirty" "$separator"
    ' bash {} ';' -- '\.git$' "$rootDir"
)
```

Comment: That first argument after the code goes into `$0` and is also used as the inline-script's name in error message, so things like `_` are quite a poor choice. `bash -c '....' bash {}`... for instance is better.

Comment: `bash -c "command $@" _ arg1 arg2` should be `bash -c 'command "$@"' bash arg1 arg2`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I was following something I saw in another example. I fixed it.