# Aliasing 'python' to 'ipython' only when 'python' is run without args

Tags: zsh, python

I thought it would be nice to have an alias (in ~/.zshrc) to have 'python' aliased to 'ipython' ONLY when 'python' is run without args (otherwise, programs won't launch).
First of all, how to express "without args" in an alias?
Secondly, what do you think about it?

Comment: Be more specific as to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: As of my ipython version (4.0.1), running ipython with a script as the first argument will run the script. Further, note that setting up an alias like this will prevent running, for example, "ipython notebook", so it may be easier to just alias python='ipython' (although I'm sure there will be some undesired side effects occasionally)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell aliases, by definition, don't give you any way to use them conditionally. They apply to anything you run from an interactive prompt.

The way you can do this is with a function instead. (See [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30964/1925) for more on why this is different.)

```
function python () {
    test -z "$1" && ipython || command python "$@"
}
```

Something along those lines in your shell's rc file will cause your shell to run this function instead of the binary directly. If the first argument is blank, it will fire off ipython for you, otherwise it will pass on all arguments to whatever python binary is in your path (note the use of `command` to force the binary rather than the function to execute and cause a recursion on itself).

Comment: This will also execute on `python ''`, and you will also execute python if `ipython` returns an exit code >0. `function` also makes this non-POSIX when it doesn't really need to be.

Comment: @ChrisDown All of those "side effects" are intentional here. If a blank argument is specified, `ipython` should be able to handle it. If `ipython` fails for some reason (such as not existing on the system), trying regular python seemed like a good option. Using `function` is just a ZSH convention, but your right it would work without that.

Comment: That isn't an alias, it's a shell function. At least in bash, aliases just replace the command name by a string of _fixed_ words; no arguments as such handled, no logic.

Comment: @vonbrand I didn't say it was an alias. In fact I said that an alias would not work for this problem and that a shell function was needed instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do it in an zsh alias, but why not stick this small shell script in your `~/bin` as `python`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -z "$1"; then
    exec /usr/bin/ipython
else
    exec /usr/bin/python "$@"
fi
```

Comment: This will also execute on `python ''`.

Comment: As if you'd actually do that :)