# Using xfreerdp with variable IP/hostname

Tags: bash, fedora, alias, freerdp

I got a very simple alias on my bash:

```
alias xfreerdpp='xfreerdp /v:ip_address /u:username /d:domain /p:password /size:1024x768 /clipboard /cert-ignore &'
```

All I want to do is to make the `ip_address` a variable so that I can type `xfreerdpp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, passing `ip_address` as an argument.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following to your `~/.bashrc` and `source` it then.

```
xfreerdpp() {
    xfreerdp /v:$1 /u:username /d:domain /p:password /size:1024x768 /clipboard /cert-ignore &
}
```

To execute: `xfreerdpp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Please also consider the security concern raised by @Nasha too.

In order to pass the `password` as an argument you can do:

```
xfreerdpp() {
    xfreerdp /v:$1 /u:username /d:domain /p:$2 /size:1024x768 /clipboard /cert-ignore &
}
```

And then execute: `xfreerdpp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx password`

Comment: Thanks @Neuron. But where what would the $1 and $2 variables be?

Comment: `xfreerdpp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx password`

$1 = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 

$2 = password

Answer (score 0):

I would personally drop the ampersand otherwise you'd need a script or a shell function. Over too complicated for a start. Here you go:

```
alias xfreerdpp='/usr/bin/xfreerdp \
    /u:username /d:domain /p:password \
    /size:1024x768 /clipboard /cert-ignore'
```

Invocation:

```
xfreerdp /v:345.16.54.12 &
```

(I know about the 345 in IP addresses, I watched «[The Net](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113957/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_33)» with Sandra Bullock ;-) )

Joke aside, just be aware that storing a password in clear form as an alias is a security breach in itself. Prefer manual authentication.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Tyvm @Nasha. I'm aware of the security risk, the problem is that sometimes, people sit with me to troubleshoot and i'm not comfortable typing my pw with them looking.