# Bash: How to create permanent substitute strings in Bash commands?

Tags: bash, ssh, bashrc

I have to often do one of: `ssh really-really-long-hostnameN`
where `N` is one of `{10001-10099}`

I would really like to be able to do: `ssh myhostN`

I have `.bashrc` entry: `export myhost="really-really-long-hostname"`

But then I have to do: `ssh ${myhost}N`

which is a huge improvement, but not quite what I wanted. Is there a way to do a substitution where I can do: `ssh myhostN` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would write a function:

```
s() {
    ssh "really-really-long-hostname$1"
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
s 10037
```

Further reading:

- [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/135943)

Answer (score 1):

Edit a file `~/.ssh/config` and add entries like this for each host:

```
Host myhostN
    HostName    really-really-long-hostname100N
```

Set permissions to this file to 0600:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Then you'll be able to use `myhostN` with `ssh` related commands (`sftp`, `scp`, etc.) instead of `really-really-long-hostname100N`.

Comment: Do I have to do this for each host, or can I do something with N to make it a one liner?

Comment: @DDauS You have to do that for each host.  You can automate the creation of the entries with a script.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:
Edit your local `/etc/hosts`  file.
Add IP and name like this

```
216.58.211.14    my.google0
216.58.211.3     mygoogle1
```

..in the shell

```
ping mygoogle1

ssh my.google0
```

will work on local machine

Another way is using aliases.

## Add to `~/.bashrc`

```
alias ssh1='ssh -2 somehost.foo -l bar'
```

next time, when bash is executed you connect by typing `ssh1`.