# Applying bash function to each file in subfolder recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, xargs, function

I am trying to write a script that will apply a bash function for each file in a directory recursively. For example if the directory `tests` had all my files and sub-directories in it, the script

```
find tests -type f -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

Works perfectly. Now I want to be able to apply a bash function rather than just echo, so I came up with something like this:

```
function fun() {
    echo $1
}

export -f fun

find tests -type f -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'fun "$@"'
```

However this only outputs a single file in tests, where before it output all the files. I would expect these two to run the same no?

Comment: You can try the exec option of find, i think will do the job.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands

Comment: Is your function even defined in that bash process?  If you say `bash -c`, you get a non-interactive shell, which doesn't look at `.bashrc`.  Secondly, does your function look at multiple arguments?  Thirdly, you should say `bash -c 'fun "$@"' sh`, because the first word after the command string after `bash -c` is assigned to `$0`, and therefore isn't included in `"$@"`. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … OK, ignore the first point; I hadn't noticed that you had exported the function.

Comment: And I hadn't noticed that you showed us the function!  (D'oh! facepalm!)  My second point is that, (as you might have noticed from your experiment with `echo`) `xargs` executes the command with all the files at once (or, at least, as many as can be passed on one command line — this is in the thousands) and not once per command.  Since your function prints only `$1` (and not all the arguments), you get only one.

Answer (score 2):

**Use a shell script.**

To quote from [this excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30964/135943):

> *Do other programs besides your shell need to be able to use it?* If so, it has to be a script.

As already noted in other answers, it may be *possible* to work around this by exporting the function, but it's certainly a *lot* simpler to just use a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# I'm a script named "fun"!  :)
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

Then you just put the `fun` script somewhere in your PATH (perhaps in `~/bin`), make sure it's executable, and you can run:

```
find tests -type f -exec fun {} +
```

Comment: Nice, I guess this is how I check all ruby files syntax: `find . -name "*.rb" -exec ruby -c {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

There two ways to solve this issue: you could either tell xargs to run command with only one argument at a time using `-n1` or loop for all arguments inside your function `fun`:

```
function fun() { echo $1 }
export -f fun
find tests -type f -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 bash -c 'fun "$@"' --
```

or

```
function fun() { while [ -n "$1" ]; do echo $1; shift; done }
export -f fun
find tests -type f -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'fun "$@"' --
```

Comment: Maybe a clearer way to loop through arguments is with a `for`: `function fun() { for a; do echo "$a"; done }`

Comment: @trosos, or just `printf '%s\n' "$@"`, since [printf is better than echo.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943)

Answer (score 1):

If you use GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
function fun() {
    echo "$@"
}
export -f fun

find tests -type f -print0 | parallel -0 -Xj1 fun
```