# How do you cycle through sequentially numbered aliases?

Tags: bash, alias, brace-expansion

I have 3 aliases. They are named echo1, echo2, echo3

How do i execute all 3 of them as part of a larger command?

```
$ alias echo1='echo 1'
$ alias echo2='echo 2'
$ alias echo3='echo 3'

$ echo1
1

$ echo2
2

$ echo3
3

$ echo{1..3}
bash: echo1: command not found

$ bash -ic echo{1..3}
echo2: echo1: command not found

$ bash -ic 'echo{1..3}'
bash: echo1: command not found
```

Solution: based on Kusalananda's answer:

```
 printf '%s\n' {1..3} | xargs -I {} bash -ic "echo{}"
```

Comment: There's an interesting question buried here somewhere, but I can't figure out what you *thought* that command would do.

Comment: I rephrased the question

Comment: What do your aliases do?  There is no situation in which this command could possibly work.  At the most, you would run one alias with the names of the other two aliases passed as arguments.  But it looks like your aliases aren't even defined in the shell you're spawning.

Comment: they are definitely defined and sourced

Comment: rewrote the question again using a different simpler example

Comment: Even if you ran `echo1 echo2 echo3` it would not accomplish what you intend, though.

Comment: @Wildcard I tried bash -ic before and it still didnt work. thats whats making me so confused. -i is supposed to call interactive mode

Comment: It appears that alias expansion is performed *before* brace expansion.  This doesn't surprise me, but I don't see it mentioned in `man bash`, which *does* surprise me.  However, aliases defined in the current shell aren't inherited by child shells, so I wouldn't expect `bash -ic aliasname` to work regardless of brace expansion.

Comment: @Wildcard yeah this is my assumption as well. I was wondering if there was some workaround

Comment: As I noted before, `alias1 alias2 alias3` would only ever run **one** alias.  So why would you want `alias{1..3}` to do that anyway?  Just run `alias1;alias2;alias3`.  If you want to run multiple aliases with the *same* arguments, you shouldn't be using aliases; you should be using a *single* function which encompasses the purposes of all three aliases.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/135943

Comment: You are right. There is no real reason to get this to work.

Comment: The solution to my real problem is a for loop with eval.

Comment: [`eval` is a problem, not a solution.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)  ;)  At least 99.9% of the time there is a better solution than `eval`.  I doubt you've hit the 0.1% here.

Comment: I was thinking to run a for loop and refer to the iterator `$i`

ie. `command$i some-parameter`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59661/discussion-between-wildcard-and-yosefrow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the order of evaluation of things, `echo$i` would be evaluated to the string `echo1` (for `i=1`) *after* alias expansion.

To be able to make use of the string as an alias, you need to re-evaluate the resulting string:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
    eval "echo$i"
done
```

If `echo1`, `echo2` and `echo3` had been *shell functions*, then the `eval` had not been needed (tested in Bash 4.4).

Your attempts with `bash -c` will not work as the aliases are local to the current shell session.

Your initial thing

```
echo{1..3}
```

would result in

```
echo1 echo2 echo3
```

Even if `echo1` had been expanded to `echo 1`, the result had been the output of the string

```
1 echo2 echo3
```

---

Personally, depending on what you'd wanted the aliases to *actually* do, I would have implemented a function:

```
dothing () {
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
```

... and then called that with

```
dothing {1..3}
```

to produce

```
1
2
3
```

Of course, that would have been achieved with `printf '%s\n' {1..3}` directly...

Comment: using the -i flag introduces interactive mode which *does* simulate a manually opened shell with sourced ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_aliases etc.

So bash -ci technically should work. but its irrelevant in this case because even if it did work yould end up with echo1 echo2 echo3 which would pass echo2 and echo3 as parameters to echo1

Comment: @yosefrow It still would not allow you to call an alias with `echo$i`.

Comment: ok i tested this just now  bash -ic works fine as long as the alias is define in ~/.bash_aliases and sourced in ~/.bashrc

Comment: It follows that if i used eval, i could definitely call echo$i. but a for loop makes the most sense i think

Comment: You just gave me a great idea!

`printf '%s\n' {1..3} | xargs -I {} bash -ci "echo{}"`

Comment: Even though my own solution achieves what i want I marked yours as accepted, because without it I couldn't have done it

Answer (score 0):

Why not making another function who execute the aliases?

```
function execute_all_aliases{
  alias1
  alias2
  alias3
}
```

Comment: Naming the function "alias" probably isn't the best choice.

Comment: @JeffSchaller true. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You could always do:

```
eval echo{1..3}\;
```

That is tell the shell to evaluate the expansion of that as shell code, that is evaluate:

```
echo1; echo2; echo3;
```

Some other variants:

```
eval echo{1..3}$'\n' # separate with newline instead of ;. Can make a
                     # difference for things like alias echo1='echo x|'
                     # alias echo2='tr x y'

eval echo{1..3}'&&' : # only run the next one if the previous one succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kusalananda I came up with the following solution:

```
printf '%s\n' {1..3} | xargs -I {} bash -ic "echo{}"
```

This will achieve the goal of executing n amount of aliases named sequentially with other command parts