# Alias a shortcut to open a url

Tags: bash

I set an alias:

```
 $ alias net="open https://www."
```

Try it:

```
    $ net google.com
    The file /Users/me/google.com does not exist.
```

How enable the alias going to open any url without the prefix `open https://www.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an alias to do that exactly, since an alias expands to the whole words of its expansion, so the net result of `net google.com` is `open https://www. google.com` (which explains why it's trying to find a file named `google.com`.)

Instead of an alias, use a function, which essentially works in the same context as an alias, but it's more generic and allows for better handling of arguments.

Something like this would work:

(In case you still have the alias set, start by removing it:)

```
$ unalias net
```

Then define a function to open the URL:

```
$ net() { open "https://www.$1"; }
```

And then try it with:

```
$ net google.com
```

See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/281844) about when to use aliases, functions or scripts in bash, which you might find interesting.