# how to remove leading space in command line argument

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, osx, alias

I am losing my mind here.. have tried every combination of functions that strip whitespace but I can't get rid of this particular whitespace

I want to write a convenience alias so that typing

```
runit cmd arg
```

results in

```
php artisan runit:cmd arg
```

I have tried all of these

```
alias runit="php artisan runit:${1}"
alias runit="php artisan runit:${@}"
alias runit="php artisan runit:${1} ${@:2}"
alias runit="php artisan runit:${1:1:${#1}-2}"
```

And I've tried many other ways to basically strip the whitespace that is always added in between the runit: and my passed first argument

The end result no matter what I've tried is

```
php artisan runit: cmd arg
```

Cannot for the life of me get rid of the space between "runit:" and a CLI argument. I've tried assigning ${1} to another variable first, can't get rid of that leading whitespace..

Hope someone can help!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/117549

Comment: yea thanks for that.. I got it working immediately by using a function. I guess I was trying to keep it as simple as possible. I guess you can use some bash functionalities inside aliases such as capturing the command line arguments but a lot of other things you can't do