# How do I source a new .bashrc in an alias that switches my shell?

Tags: bash, sudo, alias, home, source

I have an alias I use to run `sudo -s` called `ssu`. I want it to also source my root session from the `.profile` in my home directory.

Other answers seem to say that this is the solution:

> `alias ssu='sudo -s && sudo -Hu root source /my_home/.profile'`

But executing `source` as root user doesn't make it the profile for *my* shell. It runs the command after I *log out* of my root session.

Is there a way to seamlessly execute `sudo -s` and `source` (as root) in a row without having to run two commands?

Comment: Probable duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function

Comment: @jesse_b I did read that post, but I'm still unaware if it's possible to seamlessly execute the `source`  as root using a function or a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session running in sudo has all its variables scoped for the lifetime of the invocation. What you have in your alias is a command, `sudo -s` which will launch a shell as root. Once you exit that shell, it will run another command, `sudo -Hu root source /my_home/.profile`. Even if that did what you thought it did (it doesn’t), it would be for a second invocation of sudo and this a separate shell session.

The `source` command in bash is a builtin, not an executable, so sudo can’t launch it as root. You could run it in a bash command, though.

Perhaps you would be best served with something like

`sudo -H bash —rcfile /my_home/.profile` ?

Comment: Thanks! That one line worked. For anyone else trying to do the same, it has to be done as a function, -rcfile doesn't work in the alias for some reason. Cheers!