# recognize symlink from symlinked folder

Tags: bash, ls, symlink

Let's say I am in console in a subfolder, that is a child (or grandchild, etc.) of a symlinked (soft) folder.

From the subfolder, if I do `ls -la` nothing indicates all the files are inside a symlinked folder.

How could I know that? Currently, I have to go to the parent folder to know that.

But it means finding by test error, testing all the hierarchy of folders until arriving to the parent (linked).

Comment: Take a look at `realpath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @ajgringo619

This solves it:

```
# includes complete left path
alias ll2='if [[ $(diff <(ls "$PWD" | sed "s|.*|$(ls -d "$PWD/")&|g") <(ls -d "$(pwd -P)/"*) | wc -l) == "0" ]]; then ls -l; else paste -d " -> " <(ls "$PWD" | sed "s|.*|$(ls -d "$PWD/")&|g") /dev/null /dev/null /dev/null <(ls -d "$(pwd -P)/"*); fi'

# or 

alias ls2='if [[ $(diff <(ls "$PWD" | sed "s|.*|$(ls -d "$PWD/")&|g") <(ls -d "$(pwd -P)/"*) | wc -l) == "0" ]]; then ls -l; else paste -d " -> " <(ls "$PWD") /dev/null /dev/null /dev/null <(ls -d "$(pwd -P)/"*); fi'
```

Answer (score 3):

The fact you navigated to the current working directory by following some symbolic link(s) is only tracked by your shell, i.e. by Bash. The path that led you here is called the logical path, it can contain directory components that are in fact symbolic links to directories. The path after resolving all the symbolic links is called the physical path.

A tool that is neither your current Bash nor any of its builtins, when it gets spawned as a separate process in the current working directory of the shell, it knows the physical path to the directory naturally, because the physical path is the one the OS associates with the process (`/proc/self/cwd` for the process). The tool can know the logical path by examining the `PWD` variable in its environment or by using anything that examines the variable. The value of the variable comes from your Bash.

In Bash the builtins `cd` and `pwd` can operate on physical or logical paths, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1312268/432690). `pwd` that is not a builtin (e.g. `/usr/bin/pwd`) can tell you the logical path only because it checks the `PWD` variable in its environment. In a symlinked directory compare these:

```
$ env pwd -L
/logical/path
$ env pwd -P
/physical/path
$ env --unset=PWD pwd -L
/physical/path
```

Note all these `pwd`s are not builtins; `env` itself in not a shell builtin and it can only run `pwd` executables, not builtins. By removing `PWD` from the environment we made `pwd -L` behave like `pwd -P`.

`ls` does not care about `PWD` in the environment. The possible discrepancy between the physical and the logical path is irrelevant for what `ls` does. You may have thought it should be different. In the first version of your question you made an incorrect assumption that all files in a symlinked directory are symlinks; with this assumption it's easy to further assume `ls` hides this fact. The truth is `ls` in some (physical) directory works in the same way, no matter what logical path led your shell to the directory.

You can detect discrepancy between the physical and the logical path by comparing the output of `pwd -P` to the output of `pwd -L` (or directly to `$PWD`). Let's build a basic warning into `ls`:

```
function ls (
   p="$(pwd -P)"
   command ls "$@"
   [ "$p" != "$PWD" ] && >&2 printf 'ls: warning: ./ -> %s/\n' "$p"
)
```

I used a function, not an alias, because `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` is quite common and I don't want to break it; also because [aliases are not for this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/108618). The highly probable existence of the alias makes the syntax `function ls …` way better than the portable `ls () …` (the latter triggers the alias).

This basic function is not perfect. `ls /some/other/dir` will never warn you about `/some/other/dir`, it will warn you about `./` (if symlinked) in spite of `./` being irrelevant in this case.

Anyway, the answer to "how could I know that I am in a subdirectory that is a (grand-…)child of a symlinked directory?" is:

```
[ "$(pwd -P)" != "$PWD" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `$(pwd -P)` to my bash prompt; this gives the real folder name instead of the symlinked one. There's no command switch with `ls` that I know of that will give you what you want. But at least changing the prompt will give you the exact location you're currently in.