# Ubuntu - Always use certain php version for certain directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

I have multiple PHPs (8.1 and 7.3). If I execute `php -v` then I get 7.3.

I need to execute some command with PHP for magento 2 e.g. `php bin/magento cache:flush`, but I need to call it with php 8.1 for a certain folder (**/var/www/company**) but I don't want to always have to specify my php 8 binary e.g. `php8.1 bin/magento cache:flush` to make it work.

Is there a way to make it always use PHP 8.1 IF I am in that specific directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty wrapper function you can use in a shell like `sh` or `bash`:

```bash
php () (
   case "$PWD/" in
      /var/www/company/ ) c=php8.1 ;;
      *                 ) c=php    ;;
   esac
   exec "$c" "$@"
)
```

Now it's enough to run `php whatever …` and one or the other executable will be chosen accordingly. You can confirm this by trying `php -v` in `/var/www/company` and elsewhere.

Notes:

- You may want `/var/www/company/*` instead of `/var/www/company/`.
- `$PWD` holds what `pwd -L` would print (see the beginning of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679957/108618)). You may want what `pwd -P` would print; if this is the case, use `case "$(pwd -P)/" in`.
- The whole function runs in a subshell, so `c` is "local" without any non-portable `local c`. Ultimately the subshell is replaced by `php` or `php8.1` executable thanks to `exec`.