# Alias command with $ sign

Tags: bash, alias

How could I run this command as an alias?

```
alias findsum='find /home/sams/ -name sum.txt -exec grep -H "$1" {} \;'
```

This should be very simple, but I am not able to make it work.

```
findsum test
find: paths must precede expression: `test'
```

Comment: Bash aliases don't accept arguments - see [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

Comment: Mmm.. they do. I use them often

Comment: I can confirm bash aliases _do_ accept argument...and most use it without even noticing too :) (eg: like the `ls` alias on most distro, which most use additional argument with...) @steeldriver

Comment: @NordineLotfi The alias doesn't accept an argument. The alias is expanded without any consideration for what follows. _Then_ the arguments are passed to the command.

Comment: So, how can I make this work `alias findsum='find /home/sams/ -name sum.txt -exec grep -H "$1" {} \;'`  I can't find an answer in the linked post and someone decided to close the question

Comment: You're right. misunderstood what was meant by the word "argument" :D @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'

Comment: @user1156544 the linked question gives you the answer - you can't do this with an alias (because aliases can't take arguments), you need to write `findsum` as a function.  e.g. `findsum () { find /home/sams/ -name sum.txt -exec grep -H "$1" {} + ; }`.