# How to have everything following a ZSH alias be placed in the middle of its definition?

Tags: zsh, alias

I have this file:

```
/Users/MYUSERNAME/asciidots/asciidots/__main__.py
```

I want to alias this so that it runs as if it was in my current directory. I was thinking something like this:

```
alias asciidots="OLDCWD=$PWD && cd /Users/MYUSERNAME/asciidots/asciidots/ && python3 __main__.py ALL_ARGUMENTS_FOLLOWING_THE_ALIAS && cd $OLDCWD"
```

but I don't know of a way to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question to make clear why the answer isn't suitable.

Comment: I made a new question, as stated in the comments of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function instead:

```
asciidots() (
    cd /Users/MYUSERNAME/asciidots/asciidots/ &&
    python3 __main__.py "$@"
)
```

`"$@"` expands to the arguments to the function, and here I used `( .. )` instead of `{ .. }` around the function body to make it run in a subshell. The subshell environment has a working directory of its own, so hopping back to the original directory afterwards isn't needed.

(That should work in at least Zsh and Bash, if I'm not mistaken.)

See: [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/170373) (the title says Bash, but most of that is likely relevant to Zsh too.)

Comment: I realize this does answer, but it doesn't work for my situation. It should be like as if I  has the entire `asciidots/asciidots/` directory was in the cwd.

Comment: @CATboardBETA, mm, what do mean exactly? When the Python process is started, the working directory of that subshell is `.../asciidots`. Of course you could also replicate the `OLDCWD=$PWD && cd && python && cd $OLDCWD` within a function too, I just don't see why it would matter.

Comment: No, I mean that it should be as if all of `.../asciidots/` was in your directory before running the function.

Comment: @CATboardBETA, I really have no idea what "as if all of .../asciidots/ was in your directory" means, and I'm not sure how it should work with an alias but not with a function. With either of the alias or function case, the working directory of the shell is the original one when the alias/function starts, and it's then changed with the `cd`, just before the `python` runs.

Comment: I'm going to make a new question which better fits what I was asking, and I will accept of this as it did answer what I said I guess.