# Can aliases use positional parameters?

Tags: bash

I have the following line in my `.bashrc`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
alias see='nano --view $1'
```

But now `shellcheck` is producing a high priority warning:

> Aliases can't use positional parameters, use a function instead.

Reasonable except for one thing: it works fine! What's going on?

Comment: I think a simple test for this is to run `see file1.txt file2.txt`. If the positional argument is valid, nano would open only one file. If it isn't, both files would be opened. Inside nano, you can switch between files with Alt-Comma/Alt-Period (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62092148).

Comment: See [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function)

Comment: you can use flags under your question and ask moderators for your concern not in edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and it *works* because `$1` is empty<sup>usually [1]</sup> and not quoted. The resulting command from `see foo` would be `see  foo`.

If you quoted it however as in:

```
alias see='nano --view "$1"'
```

It would become `see <empty> foo` and you would open a *new buffer* in addition to `foo` in `nano`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
`$1` is expanded to *whatever the value of the shell's first positional parameter is* - in an interactive shell that's *usually* nothing (since interactive shells aren't typically invoked with positional parameters), however there's nothing to stop it from being set to something arbitrary (for example with the [`set` shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) / `help set`) - `set -- foo bar; see baz` for example would open `foo` then `baz`. <sub>(Freely copied from comment by [@steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) as it is an important note.)</sub>

So do not *trust* it is always empty.

---

You can also try:

```
$ alias e='echo @$1@'
$ e foo  <-- would become: echo @$1@ foo
@@ foo
|  |
|  +--- foo is next string
+------ $1 is empty
```

---

*Under the hood* so to speak you would see [something like](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

```
execve("/bin/nano", ["nano", "--view", "foo"], 0xabc...)
```

and for the quoted version:

```
execve("/bin/nano", ["nano", "--view", "", "foo"], 0xabc...)
```

In the main function of `nano`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

`argc`, (argument count), would be 3 and 4 respectively and `argv`, (argument vector / array), would be the strings in the square brackets.

---

You can use:

```
alias see='nano --view'
```

Then by issuing:

```
$ see foo
```

`foo` will be `$1`, (not really `$1` but in comparison), and the command will expand to:

```
nano --view foo
```

If you need to restrict nano to *only open `$1`*, (first argument), you would need a function because:

```
see foo bar
```

would expand to `nano --view foo bar`

Then you could use something like:

```bsh
see() {
    nano --view "$1"
}
```

Then you would *discard* any argument above `$1` and when `execve` is called it would always be:

```
execve("/bin/nano", ["nano", "--view", "filename"], 0xabc...)
```

where `filename` is `$1` in `bash`. Nano would not see `$1`, only the value. Bash takes care of that.

---

When one use a shell function the arguments are defined as positional parameters, `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, …, and the *function* has access to these. An alias is not treated as a function hence it does not have access to these parameters / they do not exists.

Try:

```
alias p1='echo "$# $1 END"'
p2() { echo "$# $1 END"; }
```

Result:

```
$ p1 a b c
0  END a b c

$ p2 a b c
3 a END
```

---

---

In general, Bash manual states:

> [For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)

and

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used ([see Shell Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions)).

---

For the `shellcheck` write up, [see the wiki for SC2142](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2142).

Comment: So what is happening is `$1` gets expanded to ... nothing? (reminder: we are talking about (a file sourced by) `.bashrc`)

Comment: @Vorac `$1` is expanded to *whatever the value of the shell's first positional parameter is* - in an interactive shell that's *usually* nothing (since interactive shells aren't typically invoked with positional parameters), however there's nothing to stop it from being set to something arbitrary (for example with the `set` shell builtin) - `set -- foo bar; see baz` for example would open `foo` then `baz`.

Comment: @ibuprofen sure, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Aliases **do not** take arguments, they are just copied as is. They *seem* to (sometimes) work (sort of). But it doesn't.

Use a shell function.

Comment: Thanks. Can I please also get a hypothesis why this one appears to work == "has worked for years on all kinds of files and respects the `--view` flag"?