# error using scp in alias: not a regular file

Tags: alias, scp

I know questions regarding this error have been asked before - but I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working in this case: for aliases.

I have the following

```bsh
alias scpip='scp $1 user@ip.edu:~'
```

I want the use case to be `scpip file` so that it copies the file into user's home directory in ip.edu.  Instead I get the error

```
scp: /home/user: not a regular file
```

It works if I do it 'manually' ie `scp file user@ip.edu:~`  . How can I make this work as an alias with an argument?

Comment: shell aliases don't have arguments; the `$1` in your alias expands to the first arg (if it exists) of the _script_ in which you invoke it, or if used interactively (as aliases usually are) to _nothing_. It is _followed_ by any arguments given in the command. Thus you are actually running `scp user@ip.edu:~ file` which tries to copy the remote directory to a local directory confusingly named `file`, but fails. You may want a function or script instead.

Comment: An alias replaces text with text, there is no logic. [Use a function instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/108618). And [quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) when defining the function. And then quote even more right at runtime because `scp` is so cumbersome it requires you to quote for the remote shell (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1685833/432690) from where it states "better don't use `scp` at all").

Answer (score 1):

If when running the command, the first argument or `$1` is a directory, which it looks like it is, then you'll need to use the `-r` switch in order to copy it whether it contains data or not. It can be run as an alias but it's more complicated and not worth the effort. It's better to just create a script.

Create a file called `scpip` in /home/directory

Have the contents as:

```
scp -r $1 user@ip.edu:~
```

Add the execute bit:

```
chmod u+x /home/directory/scpip
```

In your `~/.bashrc`, add the line

```
export PATH=/home/directory:$PATH
```

Source the init:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Lastly, run the script with:

```
scpip file
```

That will use the first argument. If it's a file,

```
scp -r file user@ip.edu:~
```

If a directory

```
scp -r directory user@ip.edu:~
```

Comment: ~ is always a directory and your solution will copy it _from_ ip.edu to the local system, which is not what OP says they want