# How to make an alias command with argument

Tags: linux, bash

I do not know what to use as the title for this question, but here is what I am looking for:

I find myself using the command below very often to find files within a subdirectory:

```
$ find ./ -type d -iname "*FILE*"
```

One way is to create a bash script with an argument and put it somewhere (e.g., `/usr/bin`).

But on some systems which I may not access those folders or maybe can not change the path,

Is there a way to create an alias?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Bash, when to alias, when to script and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/86440)

Comment: What argument is the title about? In your command there are five arguments. An [alias simply replaces text with text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/108618), it can turn `myfind` into `find ./ -type d -iname`, thus `myfind "*FILE*"` will become `find ./ -type d -iname "*FILE*"`. So yes, this *looks* like an alias taking an argument, but it's not; the "argument" is just a piece of text that *doesn't get replaced and remains as-is*. If you mean another argument then no, because the argument would need to appear in the middle of the resulting string.

Comment: You can place a script in a directory in your `$HOME` directory (typically `$HOME/bin`), and just add that to your `$PATH`.

Comment: The answers to the duplicate should be enough (please let me know if they aren't). You are looking for something like adding `alias my_find='find ./ -type d -iname "*FILE*"'` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @terdon yes sir this is what I had in mind